# Верно ли, что существовал суффикс "ЬН"?

Tags: морфемика

Верно ли, что некогда употреблялся суффикс "ЬН" со сверхкратким гласным "Ь"?

Answer (score 4):

Верно.

http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.70
В памятниках письменности XI века встречаем варианты написания типа благословеный и благословеньный. К производящей основе добавляется суффикс -ьн-. Слова какой части речи образуются с его помощью? Преимущественно имена прилагательные. Суффикс этот не первообразный. Самый простой и исходный его вид -н- находим в словоформах типа данъ, званъ, бранъ (ср. браная скатерть). Их нельзя назвать причастиями страдательного залога прошедшего времени, поскольку они еще не развивают именно такое залоговое значение, а являются только отглагольными прилагательными. В древнейших рукописях и церковнославянских книгах сохранились и вовсе неизменяемые прилагательные типа свободь. Они оканчивались на сверхкраткий звук, который в благоприятных условиях и сейчас произносится как [э], на письме он изображался буквой ь, откуда старое название этой гласной — «ерь» (ее же новое название — «мягкий знак»). Если первообразный суффикс -н- присоединялся к таким основам имен прилагательных (не глаголов! подчеркнем это), то возникало уже вполне оформленное современное прилагательное. Оно изменяется по родам, числам и падежам, а также известно в краткой (именной) или полной (местоименной, поскольку склоняется как местоимение) формах: свободь-н-ый, сободьнаго, свободьному как той, того, тому. В этом слове произошло переразложение: гласный производящей основы ь, попав в соседство с суффиксом -н-, составил с ним единую морфему и в дальнейшем стал с ним прочно ассоциироваться как образовательный суффикс прилагательного -ьн-: свободь-н-ый >свобод-ьн-ый. В результате появился новый очень продуктивный суффикс имен прилагательных -ьн-

Comment: Людмила, I like your answers very much.